# How do i start a cloned github project (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

i am just starting with RoR and working through some tutorials, there is however a particular piece of code on github that i would like to look at, i have cloned it to my local and cd into the project but 'rails s' does not seem to start the server - any ideas what i need to do?

Comment: Do you have rails 3 installed with bundler? Did you run `bundle install`?

Comment: hi David, 'could not locate Gemfile'

Comment: Could you let us know which project on Github you're trying to run? Are you sure its Rails 3 and not 2.3?

Comment: https://github.com/akosma/cortito  and i must be honest i can't see if its 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a Rails 2.3.2 app. `rails s` was introduced in Rails 3, so you'll have to use the older `script/server start` command.

Also, you're going to need rails 2.3.2, which you can install with `gem install -v=2.3.2 rails`. There's also the possibility that you're missing some required gems, which you'll find out about by running the app and watching for load errors.

Also, make sure you're running Ruby 1.8.7, not Ruby 1.9.2. Rails 2.3.2 does not work with Ruby 1.9.2

Comment: many thanks trotter, could i ask how you could tell?  Also, is it possible to take parts out and re-do them in my rails 3 app or is that unwise?

Comment: At the top of `config/environment.rb` is a line that sets RAILS_GEM_VERSION to 2.3.2. As for ripping out parts of the app, it _may_ work. There's a number of changes from 2.3.2 to 3.0.4 though, so you may have to change a bit of code to make it work.